# Handle subscription renewals via the in-app Google Play dashboard

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, in-app-purchase

Implemented in our subscription app, we validate it via the backend on Google, informing the token and the purchase ID. But when a user renews through the Google panel, we cannot know which token

What parameters can we use to activate the new renewed subscription through the Google Play panel? Since the purchaseToken and orderID are different from the previous one registered in the backend.

Thanks!